# append new row for each run of function

Tags: r, append

I am trying to append a new row to a matrix for each time I run a function. I reckon, the first time the function is run a matrix is created and the succeeding times, a new row with values is appended.

Here is some dummy data. Lets say `x` and `y` are sides of rectangle and `z` some sort of ID. In reality, these are not known in advance, but outputted by the function. The real function takes a species directory as argument, reads shapefiles, merges polygons and does a bunch of other things, but outputs the surface area. For each species (i.e. run of function) I would like to store each outputted area in a matrix or a data.frame for further analysis instead of outputting it to individual variables.

```
myfunc <- function(x, y, z){
  area <- x*y
  id <- z
  tmp <- cbind(area,id)
  assign(as.matrix('mtrx'), rbind(tmp), envir=.GlobalEnv)

}
```

The above obviously only creates the matrix and overwrites it each time the function is run.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The first argument needs to be a name of the object to assign too. Why are you converting the string to a character matrix? Does this `assign('mtrx', ....)` work?

Comment: The matrix `mtrx` is created once you run the function...

Comment: OK, but my point is the first argument to `assign` is a character vector of the name you want the thing assigned to, not a matrix. Read `?assign`.

Comment: I am fairly certain that this code is not what you mean to do: `as.matrix('mtrx')` .   It happens to work by coincidence because you are creating a character matrix of dimension `1 x 1` which is being coerced to a vector, which happens to be of length `1`. But it is certainly not (I am guessing) what you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic idea.

```
myfunc <- function(ID) {
  # do a bunch of stuff based on ID
  # calculate area
  area <- 2*ID + rnorm(1,0,10)   # fake the area...
  return(c(ID=ID,area=area))
}

ID.list <- rep(1:100)   # list of ID's
result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(ID.list,myfunc))
# head(result)
#      ID       area
# [1,]  1 -14.794850
# [2,]  2  13.777036
# [3,]  3  17.807578
# [4,]  4  21.070712
# [5,]  5  11.904047
# [6,]  6   3.735771
```

Return `ID` and `area` as a named vector with `c(ID=ID, area=area)`. Do this for all ID's with the call to `lapply(...)`. Then bind them all together using `do.call(rbind,...)`.

Comment: @jihoward: Thanks for commenting. Ah, yes, this looks like a good approach! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If, as in your example, you know the values for `x`, `y` and `z` in advance, it makes sense to say something like:

```
> f1 <- function(x, y, z) c(x*y, z)
mapply(f1, x=seq(4), y=seq(4), z=seq(4))

>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    9   16
[2,]    1    2    3    4
```

If the values for these variables are returned by another function, then perhaps best to store them until you're ready to run all the values through the final function (e.g. `f1` above).

You say

> a new row with values is appended

but in RAM a new matrix is *created* (`assign`ed) with the new row added each time you append. (You're in [Circle 2](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)). 
For small sized data this is not likely to be a problem in practice.

Also, using `assign` can make scoping awkward when calling a function within an environment (e.g. another function), so generally best to avoid if possible. There's usually a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. `(..) the first time the function is run a matrix is created and the succeeding times, a new row with values is appended` was just how I wanted it to be, hence the `only creates the matrix and overwrites it each time the function is run`.

Answer (score 1):

I *highly recommend **against*** this method, but you need to use `get` in that last line

```
assign('mtrx', rbind(get('mtrx', envir=parent.frame()), tmp)), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Why are the reasons for recommending against it? The function I have in reality is merging polygons (species distributions) and calculates the surface area. The input argument is a species. I just wanna put all the calculated areas into one matrix or dataframe for further analysis.

Comment: The obvious alternative to assigning into a different environment is to pass the matrix along.  The reason for the recommendation against the assignment method is because there is little gained from not passing the matrix, while there is much vulnerability for bugs and faulty results to be introduced.   It is relatively harmless assuming that your code is only a few simple lines, but even then, this introduces unnecessary complexity in the code. In other words, I cannot think of a single good reason to this, but can think of many bad reasons not to do it.